# How to fetch file contents instead of the file using a cron

Tags: php

I have gotten as far as downloading a file from an external folder into a directory in my website.

The code;

```
<?php

    $txt = file_get_contents('https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IPNaCKwzdWRVOq30saI_pIBLcL62g4_2zMmjK54yD3E/edit?usp=sharing');
     file_put_contents('import.txt', $txt);

 ?>
```

I have the cron file in a folder in the same directory

`https://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-child/test.php`

The code runs and a file is downloaded into the same directory with name import.txt

But the challenge is that it appears the page is downloaded as an HTML document and contains lots of CSS codes which don't exist in the file that is being downloaded.

You can check how the file I'm downloading looks like here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IPNaCKwzdWRVOq30saI_pIBLcL62g4_2zMmjK54yD3E/edit?usp=sharing

So basically the downloaded file doesn't contain the target file contents. All I'm looking for is to download the file as it is without any additions.

Thanks

Comment: That link takes you to the Google Docs web page, which then shows the document within it, ready for viewing or editing. That's why when you request that URL you get lots of HTML and CSS with it, just the same as your browser does when you go there. You would need to get hold of the direct download link for that document instead.

Comment: Or use the appropriate API. For instance: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads (I never used this, but this comes up when I google it).

Comment: Solved this by getting the direct download link as suggested. Used some Chrome extension for this. Thanks